# System Call Issues in C++

Tags: c++, performance, system

I'm writing software that requires a system call to Weka at the bginning of `main()`. The call is as follows:

```
printf("Creating neural netowrk...\n");
system("\" java -cp \"FILEPATH\weka.jar\" weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron -t \"ML_data.arff\" -d \"MLPnn.model\" \""); 
printf("Neural network created.\n");
```

But the console pops up with `Creating neural network...` and never advances.

I've tried just entering the command into the window itself, and it works fine. I'm pretty sure all my filepaths/quotes are right, because I had trouble with them before and it gave me errors. Now it just appears that the program is stuck.

It should be noted that this system call has worked before, and remains unchanged. The program around it has changed immensely, but as I said, this is literally the first set of instructions that gets executed.

Is there a way to troubleshoot this, or a common solution to the problem? I don't have a very good idea of the inner machinations of `system` calls, and wonder what could be the underlying cause (memory, hardware, etc.).

Comment: The command line appears to be ridiculously overburdened with redundant quotes.

Comment: I don't like the space in front of "java", or how the entire system parameter string is double-quoted, but I'm not sure that would cause a problem. that didn't have any other symptoms (like an error return value).

Comment: Can you print something from within the called program?  Also, when testiing such things, it may be a good idea to do `fflush(stdout)` after the second `printf`.

Comment: There seems to be an extra `"` at the end.

Comment: looks like there's a unescaped slash after your FILEPATH... should be FILEPATH with two slashes... might be causing it to not find the jar file.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
system("java -cp \"FILEPATH\\weka.jar\" weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron -t \"ML_data.arff\" -d \"MLPnn.model\" ");
```

Just removed the first '\"' and added an extra '\' after FILEPATH.

Comment: This didn't work. I read in a post on here that `system` calls `cmd` to execute the call, so the parameter has to be wrapped in an extra set of quotes, like I had. The lack of a double slash after FILEPATH was a typo in my post.